# Как получить массив из ресурсов вне класса?

Tags: android, kotlin

Мне в интерфейсе нужно получить string array из ресурсов. Но обычным способом не получается, т.к. нет контекста и я не могу вызвать resources:
`private val arrayStringsSpheres = resources.getStringArray(R.array.listDefaultSphere)`

Сам интерфейс:

```
@Dao
interface LifecycleItemDao : CrudDao<LifecycleItem> {
    private val arrayStringsSpheres = resources.getStringArray(R.array.listDefaultSphere)
}
```

Какие есть способы получить array из resources?

Comment: Контекст можно получить, или передавать его при вызове функции. Получить можно getApplicationContext, getContext, getActivity

Comment: @ArtyMorris думал об этом. Но как я контекст передам в интерфейс?

Comment: В функции параметр (Context ctx), а вызов fun(getApplicationContext). И в функции уже использовать ctx как контекст